# What is the best way to pass certain attribute values from one object to another in OOP?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Considering a class A that instantiates from a class B. Class B requires certain values from an instance of class A. What is best-practice, in terms of the SOLID or other design principles, for passing these values from A to B:

1. by passing the *whole instance* of A to the constructor of B
2. by just passing the *necessary attribute values* from an instance of A to the constructor of B
3. *depends* on the situation?

In case of (3), which criteria would favour one or the other solution?

(I do not know if this has an effect on the possible answers, but I am coding in Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of an open question, and I would say it depends on the situation. Since you specifically say that B will be instantiated from A, I assume **D**ependency Injection (the D from SOLID) is out of the question. I would then focus on the **S**ingle-responsibility principle, in addition to the general goal of keeping code as clean as possible.

A couple of things to consider:

- **How many "values" will B actually require?** If B only requires one or two simple values, then I would pass them in as parameters to keep it clean and simple. If it needs more than that, then you could either pass the whole of A (or a reference to it) in as a parameter, and let B pick what it needs from there, *or* create another class (**C?**) that contains exactly those values that are needed. That will keep the constructor signature of B fairly clean, and make it less burdensome to add / change the data passed into it (it will probably be easier and less messy to modify C later than to modify the signature of B, and all calls to it).
- **Where will B be used?** If it will only ever be used by A, then it might make sense to let B fetch data directly from A as needed. If it will be used other places and by other classes, then it might be better to minimize any dependency on A, and make sure it has everything it needs from the get-go. This also applies if there is a chance B will need to be serialized and stored or sent over a network, etc., as it might then not have access to A.

The optimal solution will vary depending on context. You might for instance think of the difference between two tightly coupled classes dealing with the GUI of a Windows Desktop application, and two classes in a service architecture, where one or both might contain data to be transferred or stored in a database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed one -- and the one that is actually most common.

You pass a **reference** to the whole object to B, which either holds the reference, or copies the values it needs during construction.

Depending on the relationship between the objects, either is acceptable.

Your solution #2 is common for those cases in which instantiating A does not require B -- that is, it could be instantiated by C which has equivalent values, or even just programmatically from values either input or computed at run time.

For whatever it's worth, I usually use #2, but if I commonly construct based on B, I will create a special constructor fascade that accepts B and harvests the values needed into the primary constructor.